# Why doesn't my GORM object save to the database?

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Consider the following code:

```
if (!serpKeyword) {
    serpKeyword = new SerpKeyword(
            keyword: searchKeyword,
            geoKeyword: geoKeyword,
            concatenation: concatenation,
            locale: locale
    )
    serpKeyword.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
}

serpService.submitKeyword(serpKeyword, false)
```

Here's the submitKeyword method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
boolean submitKeyword(keywordToSubmit, boolean reset) {
    def keyword = SerpKeyword.get(keywordToSubmit.id)
```

No error is raised when I call `serpKeyword.save`, but when I get into the `submitKeyword` method, `SerpKeyword.get(keywordToSubmit.id)` returns null. What could be preventing this from saving?

**Edit**

Changing `REQUIRES_NEW` to `REQUIRED` seems to do the trick. Here's what I *think* is happening.

The code that calls `serpService.submitKeyword` is located within a service method. From what I understand, service method's have a default propagation strategy of `REQUIRED`. Since all this database writes are happening within the context of a transaction, the writes are queued up in the database, but not actually executed against the database until the transaction is completed, according to the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#persistenceBasics):

> Note that flushing is not the same as committing a transaction. If
>   your actions are performed in the context of a transaction, flushing
>   will execute SQL updates but the database will save the changes in its
>   transaction queue and only finalize the updates when the transaction
>   commits.

We call `serpService.submitKeyword` before our transaction is actually finished. That method starts a completely new transaction where our `serpKeyword` is not available. Changing it to `REQUIRED` works because we are now operating within the context of our parent transaction.

Comment: It could be that you have some domain fields that are null or not valid. Try setting all domain fields to some valid values.

Comment: @ToddMurray: I've set the `failOnError` property; if my record were invalid, wouldn't an exception be thrown? Also worth noting: if I wrap the creation of my `SerpKeyword` in a `withNewTransaction` block, it saves to the database just fine, but then the record can't be updated later down the road, possibly due to a locking issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your code pass through `serpKeyword.save()`? If you inspect in the debug the instance that's passed to the service, you can see the id not null?

Comment: Have you tried `serpKeyword.validate()` before doing a save?

Comment: @SérgioMichels: yes, the object that's passed to the service has a non-null id.

Comment: Well, have you tried testing the save instead of failOnError? `if(serpKeyword.save(flush: true))`

Comment: @SérgioMichels: I would assume that a newly created object that can't be successfully saved would not have an `id`. Is that assumption incorrect? In any case, yes, I tried what you described before trying `failOnError`. Neither scenario indicates any type of failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think some part of the stack is being lazy.  I've ran into this behavior with Hibernate, if that's what you're using.  I'm not sure it's an approved maneuver, but you could clear the session before calling `submitKeyword` like so:

```
long keywordId = serpKeyword.id
SerpKeyword.withSession{it.clear()}
serpService.submitKeyword(keywordId, false)
```

And then change the method to:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
boolean submitKeyword(keywordId, boolean reset) {
  def keyword = SerpKeyword.get(keywordId)
```

Then I bet the `.get()` will work.  If you have other objects in the session you need.  You will need to lift those out by storing their id's and `.get()`ing them as well.

Comment: Please see my edit. Are my findings consistent with what you're suggesting?